# A 'using' statement compiles with g++, fails compilation with clang

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, clang

I have code of the following structure (which is of course much more complex in reality, especially "Base" is a three-liner, but I've tried to capture the gist of it):

```
template <class T>
class A {};

template <class T>
class B {
public:
    B(){};
};

template <class T>
class C : public B<A<T>> {
public:
    using Base = B<A<T>>;
    using Base::B;
};

static const C<int> c{};
```

The code compiles fine with g++ via

```
g++ -c test.cpp -std=c++11
```

However, with clang++ I get an error message I don't really understand

```
clang++ -c test.cpp -std=c++11
```

> test.cpp:14:14: error: dependent using declaration resolved to type without 'typename'
>         using Base::B;

Is there anything wrong with my code or is this a bug in clang?

Note: When writing `using B<A<T>>::B;` it compiles fine with both compilers, but this not a real solution to my problem.

Edit: clang version is 3.5.0, gcc version is 4.9.2

Comment: When using inheriting constructors, the `using` names the constructor, not the type, so `typename` is wrong. Anyway, `using Base::Base` should work - there is a special rule in name lookup that resolves it to the constructor. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e01aeb4d26b312e

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. `using Base::Base` is a nice solution for my production code. However, the question remains whether `using Base::B` is valid. To me, the wrong mentioning of `typename` suggests there is something wrong with clang. I'm no expert in C++ however.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a clang bug. There's no reason why `using B<A<T>>::B;` and `using Base::B;` should be treated differently.

Comment: Thanks, I've filed a bug report and will update this question accordingly: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22242

Comment: @user2188211: So answer your own question and accept, then :-)

Comment: This'd be shorter if you used `struct` instead of `class` and therefore did not need to write `public` everywhere ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This case has been discussed in the C++ committee (according to Richard Smith https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23107#c1) and things have gotten clearer now:

```
using Base::B
```

is *not* intended to be valid code.

The following method is the correct way to express constructor inheritance when introducing a class alias `Base`:

```
using Base::Base
```

However, the error messages produced by clang are misleading and will hopefully be solved as part of this bug report (https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22242).

Comment: 3 years later, the bug is still unresolved and error message is still misleading :(

Comment: The corresponding C++ core issue is: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2070

Answer (score 7):

From section 12.1:

> Constructors do not have names

So the usual rules for qualified lookup do not apply.  Instead you have to rely on the special rule for constructor lookup (section 3.4.3.1):

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored    and the *nested-name-specifier*  nominates a class `C`:
>
> —   if  the  name  specified  after  the  *nested-name-specifier*,  when  looked  up  in  `C`,  is  the  *injected-class-name* of `C`, or
>
> —   **in a *using-declaration*  (7.3.3) that is a *member-declaration*, if the name speciﬁed after the *nested-name-specifier* is the same as the *identifier* or the *simple-template-id*’s *template-name* in the last component of the nested-name-specifier**,
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class `C`.

So you can certainly write

```
using Base::Base;
```

instead of

```
using Base::B;
```

Your original version should work under the first bullet point, but injected-class-names get complicated when templates are involved.  Just go with the simpler version `Base::Base`, which additionally is more readable.  Anyone who sees that instantly knows you are naming a constructor.